# Ionic2: loading dismiss not working

Tags: spinner, loading, ionic2

Loading component in ionic 2 working fine, for present the loading i've used below code.

```
let loading = Loading.create({
    content: "Please wait..."
 });

this.nav.present(this.loading);
```

**but my Question when i've  using** `this.loading.dimiss();` **it's not working any suggestions plz ?**

Answer (score 1):

Are you calling this from a callback of an Asynchronous function?

If so you will have to do something like

```
let loading = Loading.create({
    content: "Please wait..."
 });

this.nav.present(this.loading);

let me = this;


asyncFunction.load(me)
.then(data => {
......... do something with data ........
// when ready close loading
me.loading.dismiss();
});
```

You need to pass a reference to this into the asynchronous function so you can keep a reference to it available to the callback

Comment: hi thank you for your response but cannot find name `asyncFunction`

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by puting the code after `dismiss()` in the `.then()` of the promise that the `dismiss()` function returns.

eg : `this.loading.dismiss().then(() => { /* PUT YOUR CODE HERE */ })`